# Dict comprehension from dict to inverse dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following data:

```py
a = {1: {'data': 243}, 2: {'data': 253}, 4: {'data':243}}
```

And I want to turn it around, so that the key is the values, and the data values is the keys. So first try:

```py
b = dict(map(lambda id: (a[id]['data'], id, a))
```

But when I do this, the 1 gets overwritten by the 4, so result will be:

```py
{243: 4, 253: 2}
```

So what I would like to get is a structure like this:

```py
{243: [1, 4], 253: [2]}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.groupby`. Just remember it requires things to be sorted by the grouping key. You can also do it manually using a `for` loop (possible using a `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a dict comprehension and `itertools.groupby()`, but since dicts are not ordered, we must work with a sorted list, because `groupby` expects pre-sorted input.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = {1: {'data': 243}, 2: {'data': 253}, 4: {'data': 243}}

# key extractor function suitable for both sorted() and groupby()
keyfunc = lambda i: i[1]['data']

{g[0]: [i[0] for i in g[1]] for g in groupby(sorted(a.items(), key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)}
```

here `g` is a grouping tuple `(key, items)`, where

- `g[0]` is whatever `keyfunc` extracts (in this case the `'data'` value), and
- `g[1]` is an iterable over dict items, i.e. `(key, value)` tuples, hence the additional list comprehension to extract the keys only.

result:

```
{243: [1, 4], 253: [2]}
```

Answer (score 3):

I felt the below code is more readable and simpler way of approaching your problem.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = {1: {'data': 243}, 2: {'data': 253}, 4: {'data':243}}

result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in a.items():
    result[v['data']].append(k)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {243: [1, 4], 253: [2]})
```